# How to create a custom COCO object detection Dataset for images with no annotations?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataset

Currently, I am working on a image dataset for object detection which have directories *images* and *annotations*.

Image folder contains all the images and annotations folder contains *test.csv* and *train.csv*.

Now each .csv file have columns image_name, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, classification. I want to convert this .csv files into coco dataset format.

But this custom image dataset contains images with no objects (i.e. no annotations). So how can I deal with images without no annotations? I need to include no annotations images while training the model so that my model can learn about no object images as well.

Folder structure

```
--data
  |
  |--images
  | |
  | |--001.jpeg
  | |--002.jpeg
  | ....
  |
  |--annotations
    |
    |--train.csv
    |--test.csv
```

Using following python code snippet to convert my dataset into coco format
Reading train and test files

```
train = pd.read_csv('./data/train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('./data/test.csv')
```

```
train_image_list = []
test_image_lits = []
train_annotation_list = []
test_annotation_list = []
info_dict = {
    "description": "",
    "url": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "year": 2018,
    "contributor": "",
    "date_created": "2018/05/05"
}
category_list = [
    {"supercategory": "none", 
    "id": 0, 
    "name": "diagram"},
    {"supercategory": "none",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "table"},
    {"supercategory": "none",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "photograph"},
    {"supercategory": "none",
    "id": 3,
    "name": "map"},
    {"supercategory": "none",
    "id": 4,
    "name": "flowchart"},
    ]
```

```
cat = {'diagram': 0, 'table': 1, 'photograph': 2, 'map': 3, 'flowchart': 4, 'nan':5}
for i in range(len(train)):
    xmin, ymin = train.iloc[i]['xmin'], train.iloc[i]['ymin']
    with Image.open('./data/images/'+train['image'][i]) as img:
        train_image_list.append({'date_captured': '',
                       'file_name': train.image_id[i],
                       'id': train["image_id"][i],
                       'license': 0,
                       'width': img.width,
                       'height': img.height})
        train_annotation_list.append({'area': 0,
                                  'bbox': [xmin, ymin, img.width, img.height],
                                  'category_id': cat[str(train["class"][i])],
                                  'id': train["image_id"][i],
                                  'iscrowd': 0,
                                  'segmentation': []
                                  })
```

Formatting the train custom dataset into coco dataset format

```
train_dataset_dict = {
    'type' : 'instances',
    'images' : train_image_list,
    'annotations' : train_annotation_list,
    'categories' : category_list,
    'info' : info_dict,
}
```

I have confusion with COCO format with no annotations and no objects, how should I format that data?

I am following this [blog](https://edgenoon-ai.github.io/signal-processing/coco-dataset-format/) for reference

Comment: Are you sure the `KeyError` is coming from `'category_id': cat[train["class"][i]]`? Because you have `nan` defined as a key in that dictionary. Is it possible that the `nan` coming from `train["class"][i]` has trailing spaces or something like that?

Comment: The `train["class"][i]` is `nan` or empty cell for certain images in `train.csv` and `test.csv` files because those images don't have objects and annotations in it and as I mentioned in question I need to include no objects and no annotation images as well into the dataset for model training.

Comment: Right, but if you're getting `KeyError: nan` then it means that it cannot find an entry in `cat` with `nan` as key - and this contradicts your definition of `cat`. If you need a default in cases where `train["class"][i]` won't be in `cat`, then use `cat.get(train["class"][i], x)` and replace `x` with whatever you want/need to return as default.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I do found a solution for it. Instead of passing value I could convert the value into string that work for nan issue cat[str(train["class"][i])] but still I have confusion with COCO format with no annotations and no objects, how should I format that data?

Comment: I don't have experience with COCO, and was just pointing out what I saw as an obvious thing with the Python. Hopefully someone else with COCO knowledge can contribute.